# Git fetch from PHP file with shell_exec using private keys

Tags: php, git, ssh, rsa, shell-exec

I have built a php script that performs a git fetch on a specific folder:

the exact command is :

```
usr/bin/git --git-dir=/home/bathan/www/sync_test/repo3//.git --work-tree=/home/bathan/www/sync_test/repo3/ fetch
```

Of course, if I run this on the command line it works perfectly.

Now, when I run this using shell_exec I get the following error:

> ```
> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```

Looking into the server its trying to connect, the exact error is :

> Apr  8 10:52:17 myserver sshd[26230]:
>   Failed password for git from
>   192.15.136.253 port 32878 ssh2

So, Ok. I guess that this shell_exec is not able to read the ~/.ssh/id_rsa key I have set up. So I give 777 permission to that file and i get this error.

> @@@@@
>   @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE
>   KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@
>   Permissions 0777 for
>   '/home/bathan/.ssh/id_rsa' are too
>   open. It is recommended that your
>   private key files are NOT accessible
>   by others. This private key will be
>   ignored. bad permissions: ignore key:
>   /home/bathan/.ssh/id_rsa Permission
>   denied, please try again. Permission
>   denied, please try again. Permission
>   denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

So I guess that git IS able to read the key file. If I put it back to the correct permissions I go back again to the first error.

Note : my apache server is set to run with my same user (bathan) and this is an ubuntu box.

This is the ssh -v Response

```
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/bathan/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for gitserver
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.myserver.com [77.171.171.229] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bathan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1023
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-1023
debug1: identity file /home/bathan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'git.myserver.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bathan/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found
..
..
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the PHP script is executed with the same user you setup `~/.ssh/id_rsa` with?

E.g. in lots of environments the webserver (e.g. Apache) is run by `www-data`. And I'm only guessing that `www-data` is not the user in whose `$HOME/.ssh/` the `id_rsa` is located.

Try to hardcode the location of the ssh-key in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitserver
Hostname fqdn.example.org
IdentityFile /home/THE-USER/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If this doesn't help, debug like so:

From PHP:

```
<?php
shell_exec("ssh -v gitserver");
```

See which keys are used in this case to get an idea why it may not work.

Comment: As I said, my apache server is set to run with my same user (bathan). I changed this on purpose on apache.conf to make sure im using the exact same user.

Comment: Rather than change apache to run as your user, why not just copy your keys to apache's .ssh dir?

Comment: That was actually very helpful! I got the debug string response and im placing it on the original post. I think the : "roaming is not allowed " could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The rsa_id was using a paraphrase and OBVIOUSLY it was not typed in by the script.

I removed the paraphrase with : ssh-keygen -p and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to everyone for their help!!